# SSRS Powershell Get-RsFolderContent - [Deserialized.SSRS.ReportingService2010] does not contain a method named 'ListChildren'

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I’m attempting to show all reports in a folder using Get-RsFolderContent from the ReportingServicesTools package.

While connected to corporate VPN I have access to SSRS through web browser including the “ReportService2010.asmx” page used for requests from Powershell.

When attempting to get data with powershell I recieve the following error (same for both lines):

```
Line 85
$Proxy.ListChildren($Item, $Recurse)

Method invocation failed because [Deserialized.SSRS.ReportingService2010] does not contain a method named 'ListChildren'.
```

Code used:

```
$ReportServerUri = "http://vmnamehere:80/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl"
$rs = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $reportServerUri -UseDefaultCredential -Namespace "SSRS"

$Attempt1 = Get-RsFolderContent -RsFolder / -ReportServerUri $ReportServerUri -Proxy $rs
$Attempt2 = $rs.ListChildren("/", $true)

$Attempt1
$Attempt2
```

Since the library is open-source, I see that line 85 of Get-RsFolderContent is that same "$rs.ListChildren" as I used above in attempt2, so no surprise that the error is the same.

https://github.com/microsoft/ReportingServicesTools/blob/master/ReportingServicesTools/Functions/CatalogItems/Get-RsFolderContent.ps1

Any idea why this ListChildren method isn't found?
Could this be some kind of credential issue?

SSRS Version 2017
Powershell Version 7.0.3

Comment: What happens when you omit the "?wsdl" from the URI?

Comment: @Graham Exactly the same message

Comment: I can confirm, running against an older server, I have success with functional the same code, with a URI without the '?wsdl'.  If you use Invoke-Webreqeust with -UseDefaultCredentials, what response to you get?

Comment: @Graham Success with status 200, but it required the -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication flag since it's a http link. result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqatP.png

Comment: I missed this the first time around: PowerShell 7.  My recollection is Cmdlet doesn't support 6 and beyond because of changes to Invoke-WebRequest, which is not backward compatible.  If you run this on against an older version should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New-RSWebServiceProxy relies on New-WebServiceProxy, which is [not available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/breaking-changes-ps6?view=powershell-6) starting with PowerShell 6.x:

> .NET Core does not support the
> Windows Communication Framework, which provide services for using the
> SOAP protocol. This cmdlet was removed because it requires SOAP.